# conditional check based on input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Using angularjs, how can i show the extra tabs based on the URL parameter.
Example :If user enters URL  http://myURL.com , it should show tab1,tab2 and when user enters the URL http://myURL.com/showAll, it shoud show tab1,tab2,tab3.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/z4h5sfcaZLDXZ8xI7KDU?p=preview

I tried using conditional check like below:

```
<div ng-show="showAll">
<div..>

//tab content
</div></div>
```

The above ng-show is only hiding the content inside the tab based on the conditional check, but i want to hide the tab3 display itself when user gives the URL http://myURL.com instead of http://myURL.com/showAll.

Any inputs would be helpful.

PS: Taken from [show or hide the element based on the user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46532947/show-or-hide-the-element-based-on-the-user-input/46533051?noredirect=1#comment80024635_46533051) , but as i said it is not hiding the tab display on the UI instead just hiding the content inside the tab based on the URL input.

---EDITED SECTION---
app.js code:

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    }).when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: 'mainControler'
    }).when('/showAll', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: 'showAllController'
    })});

    myApp.controller('showAllController', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.status = true;
});
```

I have added $rootScope.status = true; in the controller which is called when the user enters the url http://myURL.com/showURL. But still the tab is hidden.

Comment: You could use param on ui-router for that purpose.

Comment: Your sample code doesn't show the use of any Router at all.  Were you planning on using `ngRoute`, `uiRouter` or some other Router for parsing the URLs?  Or just reading the URL parameters by hand?

Comment: I want to use ngRoute, Can you please suggest .As mentioned in my post i was able to hide the tab content not the tab display. @Claies

Comment: so after you install `ngRoute` and then make a route for `/showAll`, the controller that is attached to that route would set the `showAll` property to `true`.

Comment: @Claies - Can you update the plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/z4h5sfcaZLDXZ8xI7KDU?p=preview . As it would be reference for the future SO users too.thanks

Comment: is that code for "please write my code for me because it's too many steps for me to learn how to write it myself"?  I'm no stranger to answering questions, but I rarely complete half finished code as an answer.

Comment: @Claies - I'm sure that my response sounded that way, please see my edited section in the post above. With the conditional check in html page, it is just hiding the content of the tab not the tab itself. I want to show/hide the tab itself based on the URL input.

Comment: well in the new plunker, you don't even have a `showAll` property anymore.  It's still not really clear what your ultimate goal is, and this feels more like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/297619) than anything. are you only ever planning on showing either 2 tabs or 3? What happens if someone tries to navigate to tab 3 manually by typing it in?  how does `/showAll` make sense with `/tab/1`, `/tab/2`, etc?  Every iteration here creates more questions, which is why I suggest that it doesn't feel like a finished concept.

Comment: to start with, I would consider converting the `tabs` into an array of objects, with `name` and `visible` properties;  then, you can independently control which tabs are visible or not by changing `visible`, and your `ng-repeat` can pair with `ng-if="tab.visible==true"`

Comment: got you. Actually my goal was to when intialy user loads the pages just show tab1 and tab2 and when user adds showAll parameter to the end of the URL ex)http://myURL.com/showAll it has to display all 3 tabs including tab1,tab2 and tab3. If user remoes showAll parameter form URL http://myURL.com it has to only show tab1 and tab2. Hope it clear's and being a newbie may be my code looks a bit of mess.@Claies

Comment: right, but as it stands now, you only have `/tab/:tabId` or `/tab/1` as valid routes.  if you put `yoursite.com/showAll`, you would be sent to `yoursite.com/tab/1`.  Were you wanting to have something like `yoursite.com/tab/1/showAll`? or `yoursite.com/showAll/tab/1?` or something else?

Comment: I want /tab/:tabID . May be i will modify it according to my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The short solution for your requirement you can put condition also inside the tab-list

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="{{ tab.tabValue == activeModule? 'active':''}}" ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
          <a ng-show="tab.status" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="tabAction(tab.tabValue,tab.tabName)">{{tab.tabName}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Inside The controller :

```
$scope.tabs=[{"tabName":"Tab1","tabValue":"tab1Value","status":true},{"tabName":"Tab2","tabValue":"tab2Value","status":true},{"tabName":"Tab3","tabValue":"tab3Value",,"status":false}];
```

Change the tab status according to URL

Check Working [Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/sLO8JiTGmyCMCTHtouRL?p=preview)

Comment: Please see my edited section in the post above. I tried to make the status as true for the showALL URL as shown in the code in the edited section of my post above.But still the tab is hidden. How to change the tab status according to the URL, any inputs?

Comment: with help of $route.current you can get the name of route and change the status of all the tab according to route name